# Will this image always load into the .py app if it's in the same directory?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I'm writing an application that I would like to use this .gif file in. If I want to execute this app with this picture in the same folder as the .py file will it simply show with this code or do I have to embed them into the app using base64? Thanks for your help.

```
jlu_logo = tkinter.PhotoImage(file="jlu-logo.gif")
jlulogo = tkinter.Label(main, image = jlu_logo)
jlulogo.place(x=255, y=230, anchor="s")
```

Comment: "Both sets of code look relatively the same" - I only see one set of code, and reference to one picture. Can you please update your question with *all* relevant code.

Comment: @MorganThrapp: no, it won't. It will load images in the current working directory, which might be different than the location of the .py file.

Answer (score 0):

you could try something like

```
import os

jlu_logo = tkinter.PhotoImage(file=os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), "jlu-logo.gif"))
jlulogo = tkinter.Label(main, image = jlu_logo)
jlulogo.place(x=255, y=230, anchor="s")
```